# derivative of functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

What is the derivative of $e^{\ln (\cos x)}$ , $e^{\ln(\sin x)}$ please show me in steps.

And can someone please solve this with clarification. $F(g(x))$ find $F'(0)$ if $g(0)=5$ , $g'(0)=8$, $f(5)=4$.

Comment: Say $y=e^{log(z)}$. Take logarithms of both sides

Comment: Ok i got the idea of the first section. How about the second one ?

Comment: Yes about e^ln(cosx). I know that it's a constant to the power of a variable so the rule says  e^ln(cosx) 1/cosx sinx . why can't I apply this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint $e^{ln(x)}=x^{ln(e)}$ bychange of base rule so we have $e^{ln(x)}=x$ also $log $ is defined for positive so that x are only permittable as solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> Notice:
>
> - $$e^{\ln(x)}=x$$

- $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[e^{\ln(\cos(x))}\right]=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[\cos(x)\right]=-\sin(x)$$
- $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[e^{\ln(\sin(x))}\right]=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[\sin(x)\right]=\cos(x)$$

Comment: Wherever the original expression is defined, of course, which is not for all real numbers.