# Derivative and composition

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

F(g(x)) find F′(0) if g(0)=5 , g′(0)=8, f(5)=4 . can someone solve this ?

the answer is 32 but I don't how

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734617/derivative-of-functions).

Comment: $$D(f\circ g)(x) = (Df\circ g)(x)\cdot Dg(x)$$

Comment: Some case is needed here as you seem to have mixed $\;f\;$ and $\;F\;$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$

For $ x=0$ you have $(f(g(0)))'=f'(g(0))g'(0)=f'(5) \times 8=4 \times 8=32$